# c#.Net Progress Bar Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I am reading data from a file and would like to attach a progress bar to this operation. I found the following code on stackoverflow - this code is due to William Daniel, Sept 20, stackoverflow post titled, " How to Change Color of Progress Bar in C#.Net 3.5"

```
class CustomProgressBar : ProgressBar
{
    public CustomProgressBar()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        // None... Helps control the flicker.
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        const int inset = 2;
        using (Image offscreenImage = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics offscreen = Graphics.FromImage(offscreenImage))
            {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);

                if (ProgressBarRenderer.IsSupported)
                    ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalBar(offscreen, rect);

                rect.Inflate(new Size(-inset, -inset));  // Deflate inner rectangle
                rect.Width = (int)(rect.Width * ((double)this.Value / this.Maximum));
                if (rect.Width == 0) rect.Width = 1;
                LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(rect,
                      this.BackColor, this.ForeColor, LinearGradientMode.Vertical);
                offscreen.FillRectangle(brush, inset, inset, rect.Width, rect.Height);

                e.Graphics.DrawImage(offscreenImage, 0, 0);
                offscreenImage.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine except the following:

1. The gradient does not seem to extend the entire width of the bar. It is there but is much more heavily concentrated near the bottom of the bar and thins out very quickly as we get to the top of the bar. Any suggestions as to how I can fix this?
2. If I place the progress bar on a form and open an Internet Explorer window over the portion of the form with the progress bar on it, some of the text from the internet window bleeds onto the progress bar in the form. I have no idea why, and how to fix this.

As an aside, how does one estimate the length of an operation that you wish to show via a progress bar?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use the in-built progress bar for Winforms?

Comment: I wanted a smooth gradient type bar and wasn't syre th ebuilt-in one would give that to me.

Comment: You can't really estimate the length of an operation. You can take a wild guess, and then cross your fingers and hope nobody notices that the progress you indicate has nothing to do with the operation. Processing a file though, you might be able to get a real indicator depending on how it's being done.

Comment: I use: int fileLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fd.FileName).Length; to get the size of file and as I read it with stream reader update the bar. This is OK but I guess there was a generic approach for other processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for first part of your question - try using following constructor for your brush:

```
new LinearGradientBrush(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, Height - inset * 2), BackColor, ForeColor);
```

Your current brush has top control point at `Y=inset` - that's why area from `Y=0` to `Y=inset` is all painted in solid color.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this suggestion but can't get the gradient to appear. I will have to play with it some more.

Answer (score 1):

You are not drawing at all in the non-filled portion of your progressbar. Try calling `FillRectangle` for area from `rect.Right` to `this.Width` with background color. It should prevent *bleeding* from overlapping windows.

Comment: I thought the following two lines of code did that:                     LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(rect, this.BackColor, this.ForeColor, LinearGradientMode.Vertical);
                    offscreen.FillRectangle(brush, inset, inset, rect.Width, rect.Height);

Comment: `rect.Width` is smaller than `Width` - you set it based on `this.Value`. The remaining `this.Width - rect.Width` are left as they were. Also, whole 3px inset is not painted and will also create bleed effect. Easiest solution would be to fill **whole** `offscreenImage` with background color.

Comment: I added the line: offscreen.Clear(Color.DarkBlue); in the second using block and this seems to work. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. And any ideas on extending the gradient?

Comment: Control points in LinearGradientBrush are in logical coordinates, not local (proper) ones - I posted another answer with tip for that.

Answer (score 1):

try this one, you don't need on each paint to create an image...

```
 class CustomProgressBar : ProgressBar
 {
  public CustomProgressBar()
  {
   this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint|ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer|ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
   this.UpdateStyles();
  }

  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
  {
   const int inset = 2;
   Rectangle rect = this.ClientRectangle;

   var offscreen = e.Graphics;
   if (ProgressBarRenderer.IsSupported){
    ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalBar(offscreen, rect);
   }

   rect.Inflate(new Size(-inset, -inset));  // Deflate inner rectangle
   rect.Width = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round((rect.Width * ((double)this.Value / this.Maximum))));
   if (rect.Width == 0) rect.Width = 1;
   LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(rect,this.BackColor, this.ForeColor, LinearGradientMode.Vertical);
   offscreen.FillRectangle(brush, inset, inset, rect.Width, rect.Height);
   offscreen.DrawString(Value.ToString(), this.Font,Brushes.Black,rect);
  }
 }
```

use

const int inset = 1;

for your other question

Comment: doesn't seem to work as well as the above suggestion. I have taken screen pics but am not sure how to post them here

Comment: aside from the bleed through issue which can be fixed as suggested above, still doesn't seem to work as well as MagnatLU's suggestion

Comment: the inset does not work at bottom of progress bar...the gradient touches bottom of progress bar rectangle.

Comment: I think it looks better, if the gradient color brush touches the bottom. It is more or less a matter of taste.